# ERROR SQLSTATE[HY093] when Im try to $query->save() using Phalcon

Tags: php, pdo, phalcon

I'm trying to do a simple update on the database but I got an error, I think its is a PDO issue, but I couldn't find the solution, I don't know what more can I do, I use Phalcon 2.0.7

*ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens*

Example Url: http://domain.com/controller/hide/8

On my Controller:

```
public function hideAction($id) {
    $query = Table::findFirst($id);
    $query->active = 0;
    $query->save();
}
```

but also I try this:

```
public function hideAction($id) {
    $query = Table::findFirst($id);
    $query->save([
        'active' => 0
    ]);
}
```

On my Model:

```
use Phalcon\Mvc\Model;

class Table extends Model {

   public $id;

   public $active;

   public $title;

   public function initialize() {

   }

   public function getSource() {
      return 'table_sample';
   }
}
```

That my dispatcher service for the database connection:

```
$di->set('db', function() use ($config) {
    return new \Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql(
        array(
        "host" => $config->db->host,
        "username" => $config->db->username,
        "password" => $config->db->password,
        "dbname" => $config->db->dbname
        )
    );
});
```

As you can see is a simple update, probably Im missing something

Comment: Are you sure $id has something in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use this `findFirst` Style :
`$query = Table::findFirstById($id);`
Or
If you want to use your approach, you must write conditions (where) statements like this :
`$query = Table::findFirst("id = $id");`

Try it & Update record.